# PhpStorm: How does one exit full screen?

Tags: ubuntu, fullscreen, phpstorm

First of all I'm a heavy user of <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + A</kbd>.

I've entered Full Screen mode on PhpStorm on Ubuntu. When I tried to exit I've typed "Full Screen" and an option called View: Toggle Full Screen mode. Once I pressed enter nothing happened.

Workaround:

I've enter in Presentation Mode and then exited Presentation Mode which took me back to the original state.

Any ideas or is this a bug?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. You can assign custom shortcut to the `Toggle Full Screen mode` action at the `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behaviour | Keymap`. This option definitely works.
2. Use `Search Everywhere` (Shift 2 times) instead of `Find Action...` -- it works there for sure.
3. In full screen mode the app menu is hidden but still should be available if you move the cursor over the top edge of the screen. At least it works like that here on Windows 7 (and now 10).
4. Accordingly to [IDEA-113344 ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-113344) there should be a button next to the clock when in Full Screen mode (it is here on Windows: the bar with menu that appears when you hover your mouse over the screen's top edge).

---

It indeed does not work via the `Find Action...` tool.